# Attempting to resuscitate a corrupt VM?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, virtualbox

My ubuntu 22 VM is corrupted and I have only 1 copy of it. It's a Virtual Box image.

What I have now is that when I try to boot the vm, it heads right into GRUB2 and stuck there.

I tried to

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.blah.blah  root=/dev/sda3
```

it returns "error: invalid magic number" which I suspect is caused by the kernel file being corrupted.

I've tried many, many solutions but none of them worked. My question is what is the most optimal course of action I should take? Scratching everything and reinstall is out of the question as I have some configurations in there that I forgot to document.

By optimal I mean least time-consuming. I have already spent 3 days grinding this cow.

Comment: @user535733 Ye know in the earlier version of windows, as in 7, xp 98 etc. you were given an option or at least a possibility to overwrite an existing installation whilst keeping all your files and programs. Is that possible for ubuntu?

Comment: You still have that option with any version of Windows or Ubuntu. You can reinstall Ubuntu by manually selecting the old partitions and NOT formatting, of course. All personal files and settings are kept but manually installed software should be reinstalled. It's that simple, you already waste a lot mire time than you would have by opting for straightforward solutions.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Hi, I tried this with ubuntu 22, there's no such option.  Have you tried it yourself? If so Could you show me how to do it?

Comment: The option is "something else"

Comment: @ChanganAuto tried. doesn't work.